Call the VBAProject sheet names in a macro
Background:
I am trying to add hyperlinks to a list of cells direct to their corresponding sheet names, where the cell values were captured in a dictionary.  Those are not like-for-like names as I have replaced spaces and special characters.
Issue:
I noticed my sheets in the VBAProject were Sheet2 as cells(2,1), so attempted a quick loop to input the hyperlinks.  I sadly found out that for i = 2 to 26 // sheets(i).name did not align with my expectations (the cells(2,1) hyperlink displayed sheet25).
Inquiry:
How do I call the VBAProject sheet name within my macro so I can have an exact match up?
Code:
    With Sheets("Overview")
        Dim i As Long:  For i = 2 To 26
            Dim ws As String:  ws = Sheets(i).Name
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(i, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:=ws & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Next i
    End With


Sheets("Sheet" & i)

Doesn't the hyperlink need to use the sheet name, not its codename? For example, if I change the codename to Foo, and then try to add a hyperlink using SubAddress:="Foo!A1", I get an "Reference isn't valid." error when clicking the resulting hyperlink. I'm struggling to see how the codename is relevant here, assuming that's what you're referring to.

SubAddress:= "'" & ws & "'!A1"

@BigBen the proporties("name") is relevent as the sheets were created in the order of the cells, so cells(i,1).value is like sheets("sheet" & i).name.  The problem is looping by sheet goes from the first displayed sheet to last displayed sheet, which is why sheets(i) =/= sheets("sheet" & i)... to look at Workcupine's response, i am using that nomenclature for this response, but in trying that in my cope I get 'subscript out of rangewhen i trysheets("sheet" & i)`

What did resolve this for me was taking /u/VBasic2008's code and modifying to add If InStr(1,Sheets(j).name,Split(.cells(i,1).value," ")(0)) then because Those are not like-for-like names as I have replaced spaces and special character... second loop through sheets.

Summative statement... Handling other people's outputs is not pleasant when you cannot see how they made them (trying to find which special characters are replayed with what).  I really appreciate those that stepped up to attempt a response and got me on the correct path.

Create 'Code-Named' Hyperlinks

Sub CreateCodeNamedHyperlinks()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Overview")
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = sws.Range("A2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    srg.Hyperlinks.Delete  
        
    Dim scell As Range, dws As Worksheet, dwsCodeName As String
        
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        
        dwsCodeName = CStr(scell.Value)
        
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.VBProject.VBComponents(dwsCodeName) _
                .Properties("Name").Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
            
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then
            sws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=scell, Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="'" & dws.Name & "'!A1", _
                TextToDisplay:=dwsCodeName
            Set dws = Nothing ' reset
        End If
        
    Next scell

End Sub


This definitely helped get me on track.  As none of the dwsCodeName will match the cells (e.g., spaces are removed in the sheet names) I used InStr after splitting the cell value and taking the first word against each sheet name.  Will mark as the answer, though can state that dwsCodeName = CStr(scell.Value) is false in all cases due to this statement in the post Those are not like-for-like names as I have replaced spaces and special characters.

Try this if it works for your needs. Feel free to change.
Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Sheets("Overview")         'first worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets   'iterate through all sheets
    If ws.Name <> sht.Name Then      'ignore the Overview sheet
        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sht.Cells(ws.Index, 1), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & ws.Name & "'" & "!" & "A1", _
            TextToDisplay:=ws.Name
    End If
Next ws
End Sub


This results in the same output issue as the code I had in the post, where VBProject.Properties("Name") = "Sheet2" does not equal Sheets(2).
